# Using sed to exclude a pattern of letters/numbers

Tags: sed

I'm working on producing a generic ID report, and my current command to grab accounts using `egrep` grabs most of the accounts I need, but obviously not any accounts ending with a number, which some of our Gen ID's do:

```
cat /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1 | egrep '^[a-z]|^[A-Z]' | egrep '[a-z]$|[A-Z]$'
```

Fortunately, our user accounts all follow the same pattern - a letter, followed by 6 numbers.  How can I use `sed` to print all accounts in `/etc/passwd` *except* those that start with a letter followed by 6 numbers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
grep -vE '^[[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]{6}:' /etc/passwd
```

would print all the lines of `/etc/passwd` except those that start with an alphabetical character followed by 6 digits (followed by `:`).

The key is in the `-v` option that tells `grep` to print the lines that do **not** match the pattern.

If you only want the user names:

```
cut -d : -f 1 < /etc/passwd | grep -vEx '[[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]{6}'
```

Or with `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^[[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]\{6\}:/!s/:.*//p' /etc/passwd
```

Note the `!` which again means *not*.

Comment: Awesome, this works perfectly - thank you!